# Can't access HTTPS on Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, https, laravel-5.5

I have one working Laravel website.
It's completely working with 'http://', but when i'm trying to use 'httpS://' it returns:
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

I try to force the system using HTTPS with the middleware. It's forcing it, when you type http://example.com it redirects to https://example.com ... but still can't load the page "Sorry...".

Also i want to note, that i'm using rewrite so i can change the public_html folder of the domain. And the code is:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/examplecom/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /examplecom/public/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ examplecom/public/index.php [L]
```

Could the error be because of that? Can someone help me with this one? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your apache/nginx config for the http and https versions of the site?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the website is on Shared Web hosting... and i don't have much access :/

Comment: i'm thinking it's Laravel error, not apache, because when i change the index and put one echo there, its fine with both http and https

Comment: Check the logs in `/storage` to see if there's a hint there as to what's going on.

Comment: Absolutely nothing :/

Comment: I found it: in the routes/web.php there was line: $domain = current_domain( url('/') ); and i just remove url('/')